# React native picker value not updated correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I am working in react native and I am using `picker` as drop down menu

```
  <Picker
         style={styles.picker}
         selectedValue={selectedsubject}
         onValueChange={(subjectValue) => pickerActivity(subjectValue)}>
          {allsubjects.map((item, index) => {
                            return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={item} key={index} />)
           })}
   </Picker>
```

`onValueChange` prop I am calling this function:

```
const pickerActivity = (val) => {
        setselectedsubject(val)
        console.log("============")
        console.log(val)
        console.log(selectedsubject)
        console.log("============")

    }
```

so when value selected from menu items I pass selected value to the function `pickerActivity` in this function I update the status `selectedsubject` to the passed value and then I console the status and the value, and in the list i have two value let say (`value1 and value2`), so let's assume I pressed `value1`, so what happened: it only console log the passed value and  for the status it console log empty string as show below:

```
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.899]  LOG      ============
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.900]  LOG      value1
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.901]  LOG      
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.902]  LOG      ============
```

and second time when I press for example on `value2` from dropdown menu, the passed value will be `value2` which correct but for the status it will display the previous item selected from menus which `value1` as shown below:

```
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.899]  LOG      ============
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.900]  LOG      value2
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.901]  LOG      value1
[Sat Jan 23 2021 19:43:28.902]  LOG      ============
```

so the problem is that status doesn't update from first time, and here my status:

```
const [selectedsubject, setselectedsubject] = useState('')
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate "Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component."

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova how to achieve that with functional components?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In the handler you can use `val` and on the next render the value will be updated, what issues do you have apart from confusing console logs?

Answer (score 1):

You should define set-state function with capital letter like this.

```
const [selectedsubject, setSelectedsubject] = useState('');
```

For now, you are calling `console.log` before the state updated.
To review the updated state, you need to use useEffect, which only fires on [state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-run-an-effect-only-on-updates):

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedsubject);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The state update using the updater provided by `useState` hook is asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately.

Even though `setselectedsubject(val)` is fired, `selectedsubject` value is not updated immediately. It will keep previous value.